# Unable to read Javascript responseXML from PHP

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, xml

I have a database of shipping zones that I want to access through an AJAX request using PHP.

PHP is not correctly generating XML for responseXML.  If I change my url to a `.xml` file then the script works.

Here is my PHP to generate XML
`

```
<?
    libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
    $country_id = intval($_GET['country']);
    $country_id = 74;
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "tradingb_data", "[s;_m@NN2;)F", 'tradingb_tradingbloc');
    if (!$con) {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
    }

    mysqli_select_db($con,"ajax_demo");
    $sql="SELECT * FROM `shipping_zones` WHERE zone_type = 'Province' and parent_zone = '$country_id' ORDER BY zone";
    $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

    echo "<?xml version=\"1.0\" ?> <shipping_zones>";
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        $row_id = $row['id'];
        $row_zone = $row['zone'];
        echo "<province> <zoneid>$row_id</zoneid><zone>$row_zone</zone></province>";
    }
    echo "</shipping_zones>";

    mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

`

Here is my Javascript
`

```
function changeCountry(){
                var e = document.getElementById(\"country_id\");
                var country_id = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
                if(country_id == 1){
                    // Display states
                        document.getElementById('display_province').style.display = \"none\";
                    document.getElementById('display_state').style.display =     \"\";
                        document.getElementById('display_state').style.visibility = \"visible\";
                }
                else{
                    // Display Province
                    document.getElementById('display_state').style.display =     \"none\";
                        document.getElementById('display_province').style.display = \"\";
                    document.getElementById('display_province').style.visibility = \"visible\";
                    // Remove current selection list 


                    // Get Provinces for country_id
                    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                    // Include fix for IE6 and IE5
                    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                    } else {
                        // code for IE6, IE5
                        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject(\"Microsoft.XMLHTTP\");
                    }
                    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                            var xmlDoc = xmlhttp.responseXML;
                            // get each property 
                            // Last known execution
                            var x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName(\"province\");
                            for (i=0;i<x.length;i++)
                            { 
                                var e = document.getElementById(\"province_id\");
                                var opt = document.createElement('option');
                                opt.value = x[i].getElementsByTagName('zoneid')[0];
                                opt.innerHTML = x[i].getElementsByTagName('zone')[0];
                                e.appendChild(opt);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    xmlhttp.open(\"GET\",\"get_provinces.php?country_id=\"+country_id,true);
                    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader(\"Content-type\", \"text/xml\");
                    xmlhttp.send();
                }
            }
```

`

I know my error is in what PHP is generating for the AJAX request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {

    var xmlDoc = xmlhttp.responseXML;
    // get each property 
    // Last known execution
    var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('province');
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {

      var e = document.getElementById('province_id');
      var opt = document.createElement('option');
      opt.value = x[i].getElementsByTagName('zoneid')[0].textContent;
      opt.innerHTML = x[i].getElementsByTagName('zone')[0].textContent;
      e.appendChild(opt);
    }
  }
}
```

i made a plunker and test it.

replace the  \" by '   and use     .textContent

http://plnkr.co/edit/fddv9rYpCcbz4zt1D9Sb?p=preview

(sorry for mislead you before)

Comment: Thanks!  I had just confirmed that it is the xml output of the PHP file myself, and your plunker confirmed it as well.  I will look into my get_provinces.php to determine why it is not being parsed correctly by the response XML command.

Comment: but you see that i uses the output as province.xml file what you  said your get_provinces.php outputs. changeCountry() is a javascript function so dont uses the escapes \" , use normal one " or '

Comment: I substituted  `xmlhttp.open(\"GET\",\"get_provinces.php?country_id=\"+country_id,true);`  with  `xmlhttp.open(\"GET\",\"provinces.xml\");`  and it works correctly.  Meaning the PHP file `get_provinces.php` is not creating an output that the Javascript can interpret.  While this fixes my immediate needs, I will continue to trouble shoot a solution for the PHP file.  I appreciated your help in finding a solution!

Answer (score 0):

This is the corrected PHP file.  The headers must be set.

Thank you to micha for helping me on this problem!

`

```
<?
    header('Content-Type: text/xml');
    header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");
    libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
    $country_id = intval($_GET['country_id']);
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "tradingb_data", "[s;_m@NN2;)F", 'tradingb_tradingbloc');
    if (!$con) {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
    }

    $sql="SELECT * FROM `shipping_zones` WHERE zone_type = 'Province' and parent_zone = '$country_id' ORDER BY zone";
    $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

    echo "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
        <shipping_zones>";
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        $row_id = $row['id'];
        $row_zone = $row['zone'];
        echo "<province><zoneid>$row_id</zoneid><zone>$row_zone</zone></province>";
    }
    echo "</shipping_zones>";
    mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

`

Comment: The corrected Javascript by micha is necessary for this correction to work.

Answer (score -1):

Where do you set the `xmlDoc`? Is there any output in the javascript console of your browser?

Comment: sorry, `var xml = xmlhttp.responseXML;` s/b `var xmlDoc = xmlhttp.responseXML;`  I will check my console, thanks!

Comment: console says I have `null` in my variable.  Which leads me to believe I need to encode the XML in PHP before it is read by `responseXML`?

Comment: @Dreamwalker which one? You can try to load a static file with the same content as your php output to check if the issue is caused by php/xml or javascript.

Comment: the console says that the variable `xmlDoc` is null.  Here is the actual console output `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getElementsByTagName' of null`